# Perl quotes surrounded by only string in array

Tags: perl

I need to place the single quotes other than number in an array.

I tried the following code but it was not working . Can anyone help me to sort it out.

```
$data = join ',', map { /'\w+'/ } @$row[0..3];
```

Input/Output :

```
Input :
[1,string test, value test, 5]
Output:
(1,'string test', 'value test', 5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To place `''` around elements that have not a single digit in them

```
my $data = join ',', map { /[0-9]/ ? $_ : "'${_}'" } @$row[0..3];
```

where `string 10 test` doesn't get quoted.

Or, to leave unquoted only pure integers

```
my $data = join ',', map { /[^0-9]/ ? "'${_}'" : $_ } @$row[0..3];
```

which quotes strings with a number in them as well, like the example above.

For non-integer numbers, there is [Scalar::Util::looks_like_number](http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/Scalar-List-Utils-1.48/lib/Scalar/Util.pm#looks_like_number)

```
use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';

my $data = join ',', map { looks_like_number($_) ? $_ : "'${_}'" } @$row[0..3];
```

what of course works for the second case (integers) as well.

Comment: You could also use [`Scalar::Util::looks_like_number`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util#looks_like_number) for the test.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, you are right, have to sort out all those "other" (than integer) numbers, don't I.  Adding, thank you